# How to get article from mysql to joomla menu

Tags: mysql, joomla

I am very new to all this, I successfully set up joomla. I could login to the admin page and create sample articles, life is good so far. 
I put all articles in one folder called "Articles" under joomla folder and populated my database with links. Is this the best place to keep my articles?

my article names are as below 1_1_1.html ..... n_n_nn.html
Now I want a selected article to showup under specific submenu.

Which file in joomla folder I should modify and How?
If there are any videos to understand this concept I would greatly appreciate. I am sorry, if its a very basic question.

Answer (score 1):

No need to modify any file for this at all. So you've created the article and now you need to tell Joomla to put that article into a menu so that your users can get to it. 
So

- go into the administrator and go to Menus | Main Menu | Add New Menu Item
- Click on "select" beside "Menu Item Type"
- Select "Single Article"
- Now select the article you want displayed in the "Select Article" area on the right hand side
- Enter a "Menu Title" for the menu item (this is the text that is displayed to your users)
- Since you want this to be a submenu select the parent menu in the "Parent Item" section

Click save and refresh the website frontend

Comment: This is a way create a static page. I have all html files on the local  drive in a folder. I updated my database and now I want to display the desired article which is stored in my database under a menu item

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean then, the instructions were for linking to a dynamic article, i.e. ones stored in the article manager rather than html files. But if you need to link to html files you can point to the html files using an "External URL" instead of selecting "Single Article".

Comment: Why would you have HTML pages at all? You should be putting the content in to an article in the admin. There should not be any static HTML pages at all.

Comment: I have html files because - used LaTeX to create my document. Now using the converters I manage to convert them to html. However here is the main reason to put it on a database. There are 24,000 html files and 24,000 corresponding audio files associated with it. And in the future I will get more data to display in the multiple of 24,000. With this much data I can not create 24,000 articles in Joomla. If you can recommend any better solution I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: OK, I see what you are doing now. Not sure that Joomla is the way to go with this though - it's not what it's made for. You could write scripts to import the data into the Joomla db as articles (it can easily handle the amount of articles that you have). Otherwise you won't be able to use most of Joomla's features - that's the route I'd recommend.

Comment: I agree with @trev. Why are you using Joomla? Is there a specific feature of Joomla you are trying to use? If not, save yourself the headache and just serve your static pages.